# JZOS batch toolkit - Integrating the JZOS Cobol Record Generator

Tags: java, cobol, zos, jcl, cics

I installed the JZOS batch toolkit (AlphaWorks version) on z/OS :

```
       - sampjcl.xmit (RECGEN ...)
       - loadlib.xmit ( JVMLDM76 ... )
       - jzos.pax (jzos_recgen.jar , ibmjzos.jar ...)
```

I'm using the jzos_recgen.jar to generate Java classes from COBOL Copybooks based on Java Class :

`com.ibm.jzos.recordgen.cobol.RecordClassGenerator (given by jzos_recgen.jar)`

After submitting the 'RECGEN' JCL I get the generated Java classes but with warnings :

```
JZOS batch Launcher Version '2.4.8 2015-10-28' does not match jzos.jar Version '2.4.3 developerWorks 2011-10-11'
```

I figure out now that the JZOS batch toolkit is provided by the IBM Java SDK, i'm using Java version J8.0_64, the resources are seperated in different folders (//mvstools , /lib/ext). But I can't find the jzos_recgen.jar or the Java Class RecordClassGenerator.

I'm trying to put the JZOS batch launcher and jzos.jar in the same version.

I'll be grateful if someone know where can I find the RecordClassGenerator on z/OS File System ? or a similar solution to my situation ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way for us to know where things are installed in your shop.  We can guess, based on our own experience, but it will remain a guess.  Ask your peers, your support staff, and/or the person who did the install.

Comment: @cschneid thanks for your cooperation. I have doubts that the RecordClassGenerator class was structured differently in Java version 8. what I'm asking about is if someone had the same warning and resolve it using "IBM Java SDK" JZOS version.

Comment: You may be better off posting this on the IBM-MAIN Listserv mailing list. Free to subscribe, and people there with knowledge of Java on z/OS.

Comment: You might want to check out Dovetailed Technology's [support forum for JZOS](http://community.dovetail.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=1).

Answer (score 3):

So you need to specify an option to force Java to use the JZOS version from AlphaWorks, not from the SDK. In the sample JCL I have from JZOS, I can see this:

```
# Force the alphaWorks version of JZOS to run overriding the SDK               
OPTS="-Djava.ext.dirs=£{JZOSAW_HOME}:£{JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext"                     
export JZOS_JVM_OPTIONS="£OPTS"
```

If I take those lines out, I get a similar error as seen above.

Comment: I take it you're using a UK keyboard as the dollar signs for the variables have come out as pounds :)

Comment: Yes, it's always an issue, when dollars become pounds and vice versa!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks James for your answer, I just resolve the problem it seems to be that JZOS record Generator has not yet been integrated in IBM Java SDK. so what we need to do is configure all the different Paths manually and adapt the COBGEN JCL sample.

This is a sample of paths configurations:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lpp/java/J8.0_64
JZOSAW_HOME=/u/USERID/jzos   

export PATH=/bin:"${JAVA_HOME}"/bin:

LIBPATH=/lib:/usr/lib:"${JAVA_HOME}"/bin
LIBPATH="$LIBPATH":"${JAVA_HOME}"/bin/classic
LIBPATH="$LIBPATH":"${JAVA_HOME}"/lib/s390x   #libjzos.so
export LIBPATH="$LIBPATH":

CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":"${JAVA_HOME}"/lib/ext/ibmjzos.jar  #JZOS_APIs
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":"${JZOSAW_HOME}"/jzos_recgen.jar    #RecordClassGenerator
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":
```

- Configure a libpath for libjzos.so     // IBM Java SDK
- Configure a classpath for ibmjzos.jar   // IBM Java SDK
- Configure a classpath for Jzos_recgen.jar // JZOS AlphaWorks Version containing the class "RecordClassGenerator"
- Delete the lines of " Force the alphaWorks version of JZOS to run overriding the SDK "